# How to filter values for Ant Design autocomplete?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I have the following handler for the ant design autocomplete, but although the state is set correctly in React, the autocomplete displays additional values instead of only the filtered ones.

```
handleSearch(value) {
        api.getUsers()
        .then(users => users.map(p => p.userName.trim()))
        .then(users => users.filter(name => name.startsWith(value)))
        .then(function (names) {
            console.log(names);
            this.setState(function () {
                return {
                    dataSource: !names ? [] : names
                }
            })
        }
            .bind(this));
}
```

The autocomplete is:

```
render() {
    const {dataSource} = this.state;
    return (
        <div>
            <div><h1>User Search</h1></div>


            Username :
            <AutoComplete
                dataSource={dataSource}
                style={{width: 200}}
                onSelect={onSelect}
                onSearch={this.handleSearch}
                placeholder="input here"
            />
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: Few things never do setState inside a loop and never do binding directly in render or in loop. Declare onelocal variable outside loop and Add all the values to a local variable inside a loop and do setState outside loop. Do binding only in constructor and in some cases when need to do directly in render then use arrow function so that .bind(this) isn’t required. The basic syntax of setState as follows this.setState({ “abc”: value});

Comment: The above is a slightly weird comment considering there is no loop in the code. And the setState syntax in the question is perfectly fine...

Comment: Thanks, the setState is called after the map and filter (the loops) have returned. I don't think this or the binding syntax is the cause.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when using an async server side lookup to provide autocomplete results. If `dataSource` is updated after input is changed, AutoComplete will not update the menu because it doesn't see the need to rerender since the input was not changed.

I work around this by setting a state prop from the `onChange( value )` and explicitly setting the `value` of the AutoComplete to this state prop. This causes the results pulldown to update.

Comment: Thanks, I tried using onChange, but have the same issue.

Comment: Sorry but I was looking at my old code and not getting things right. My first answer was going in the wrong direction. I have looked again and changed the answer to address the real issue.

Comment: Render is being called after the input is changed. The autocomplete seems to add the values from the names array, instead of replacing. This means the autocomplete displays options for the previous searches which are not relevant. If I use a hard coded array like ['one','two','three''] this does not happen, on the second search I only get three options not 6 (one, two,three,one,two,three).

Comment: So you are saying that with your `api.getUser` call if you are logging 3 entries in the names array, and then the menu pops up those three plus whatever was in the previous request? Even if `state.dataSource` doesn't have the copies? Then I would say you are doing something weird which is not visible in the code you have shown above....